# Way to pick the tightest fitting matching regex from a list of regexes for a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings and a list of regexes. My goal is for each string, find the matching regex. Of course, sometimes multiple regexes in my list will match a given string. In this case, I want some way to rank them.

Basically, something that would award static parts matching or tighter fits. As an example, suppose my regexes are `.*:.*` and `STARTING:\d+`, and my string is `STARTING:18`, then obviously I put more faith into the second regex being a better match, because it matches the static content and predicted the last characters would be digits and not just anything.

I'm not exactly sure I see how the overall algorithm would go though, and whether or not I'm describing a real quality (tighter match) or if it would come down to some sort of heuristic 'score' I'd have to assign to each match.

I'm working in python if that makes any difference.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure, but isn’t this kind of ordering statically possible by evaluating the expressions? E.g. for your example, you already know that if both `.*:.*` and `STARTING:\d+` match that the second will be a lot more relevant than the former.

Comment: I think it would have to be a heuristic, because most regexes match infinitely many strings and it is not always easy to compare infinities. As a starting point, I would suggest breaking up the regex into tokens and assigning a score to each token: say -1 for bare characters, 10 for `\d`, 50 for `.`, 100 for `+` and 200 for `*`. This doesn't always give great results though, eg. `*-*` has a higher score than bare `*`...

Comment: You may also rank them by accuracy, then length of the regex, or a balance between them (by giving score). But then you need a good set of test strings, so that you can test how flexible the regex is.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of approaches - these are just "steps in the direction".

First - in Python you can compile your regex with a `debug` flag, which gives you information about *how* it is interpreting your regular expression.

Example:

```
import re
p = re.compile('STARTING:\d+', re.DEBUG)

literal 83
literal 84
literal 65
literal 82
literal 84
literal 73
literal 78
literal 71
literal 58
max_repeat 1 65535
  in
    category category_digit
```

I would say that the more literal digits you are matching, the fewer possible strings can match. Similarly, when you have `max_repeat a b` followed by `in category category_digit`, you know you can have 10 digits in 1 to 64k places. If you wanted to compute all the possible strings that could be matched, the number would be very large. A bit easier (and more sensible) to compute the *logarithm* of that number. For every line in the debug output you can figure out what that value is.

In this case, it would be

```
0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+(65535)*log(10)
```

quite a large number. But if you used the other expression

```
p = re.compile('.*:.*', re.DEBUG)
```

you get

```
max_repeat 0 65535
  any None
literal 58
max_repeat 0 65535
  any None
```

And your "entropy" would compute as log(255) * 65536 + 0 + log(255) * 65536

More than 4 times bigger…

This will be a tricky thing to implement - especially if you start adding look around etc. But for simple expressions it can be done - and it should give you some sense of which is the 'best' expression.

It would be even better to look at the output of a tool like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/debug.html) which turns the inner workings of its regex engine into 'understandable' output - you can see exactly what it is doing / trying, and how it eventually comes up with its match. Taking that approach would be ideal, but it's Herculean.